# DPI resolution is causing issues when converting from tiff to Pdf

Tags: .net, pdfsharp

I have an issue with converting .tif to .pdf. Basically for every document wherever the DPI is 96 for both horizontal and vertical, the conversion only capture the top left corner of the document - it is extremely streched. However, in cases where the document has DPI 204 for horizontal and 196 for Vertical it is being displayed properly. Is this something I need to address in my code (below), or is it necessary that I update the DPI resolution for each page of my document (which I would have to do programatically) so that dpi is 204 and 96 before converting it to pdf.

```
    Dim destination As String = FileName & "pdf"

    Dim MyImage As Image = Image.FromFile(FileName & "tif")

    Dim doc As New PdfDocument()

    For PageIndex As Integer = 0 To MyImage.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page) - 1
        MyImage.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, PageIndex)

        Dim img As XImage = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(MyImage)
        Dim page = New PdfPage()

        If img.PixelWidth > img.PixelHeight Then
            page.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape
        Else
            page.Orientation = PageOrientation.Portrait
        End If
        doc.Pages.Add(page)

        Dim xgr As XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages(PageIndex))

        xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0)
    Next
    doc.Save(destination)
    doc.Close()
    MyImage.Dispose()
```

Comment: Use the DrawImage(XImage, Rectangle) overload to get a predictable size.

Comment: @HansPassant - not sure where to include this.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks got it to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDF pages do not have any DPI (vector format).

With Windows you usually get 96 DPI for images where no DPI information is available.
If the image was scanned with 200 DPI, but Windows report 96 DPI, the image in the PDF will have double size and you will only see a quarter of the scanned image (assuming you draw a scanned A4 page onto a new A4 page).
204/196 DPI sounds like Fax format, so I assume we are talking about scanned pages.

Hans Passant already gave you the solution: specify the destination rectangle when calling `DrawImage` and you can have all images fill the entire page.

Comment: Yes the documents that Im trying to convert are mostly fax documents. Most of them are 204 by 96 but some of them are 96 by 96 which causes the issue.